# Show that $s − r = \sup \{ a − a^\prime \vert a, a^\prime \in A \}$ and $r − s = \inf \{a − a^\prime \vert a, a^\prime \in A \}$

Tags: real-analysis

So far this is what I have:
I've seen online the proofs for:

1. inf(A) = - sup(-A)
2. inf(B) = − sup(A)
3. sup(A+B) = sup(A) + sup(B)

Using some of the above formula I came up with:
s - r = sup(A) - inf(A)
= sup(A) - [-sup(-A)]
= sup(A) + sup(-A)
= sup(A - A)

Here is where it doesn't quite make sense. Is the way I'm trying to prove (a) wrong? Any help is very appreciated thank you.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: As @Shaun alluded to, you need to learn MathJax if you're going to ask questions here. See my edit of your title for guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always when dealing with questions about $\sup, \inf$ and some equations involving those quantities, it is useful to go back to the basic definition and characterizations. Indeed, you yourself say that "you've seen online the proofs of" some facts. This is not *per se* but a lot of equalities involing those quantities *seem* true, and are not, so it is good practice to actually prove things.

Now, back to our problem. We will simply use the basic definitions, and nothing more.

For a set $A \subset \mathbb R$, $\sup A$ is the smallest upper bound of $A$, and $\inf A$ its greatest lower bound - assuming $A$ is bounded.

Now, to show that $s - r = \sup\underbrace{\{a-a'\;|\; a, a' \in A\}}_{A_1}$, we need to show that it is an upper bound of this set, and that no other upper bound is smaller than $s-r$.

1. Let $x \in A_1$. By definition, there exist $a, a' \in A$ such that $x = a - a'$. We know that $a \leq s$ because $s = \sup A$, and $a' \geq r$ so $-a' \leq -r$.
   Combining those two inequalities, we get $a-a' \leq s-r$ and so $s-r$ is indeed an upper bound of $A_1$.
2. Let $p$ be an upper bound of $A_1$. Suppose that $p < s-r$. This means that $p+r < s$ so $p+r$ cannot be an upper bound of $A$ because $s = \sup A$ is its least upper bound. Hence, there exists $a \in A$ with $a > p+r$. Using the same reaoning, we find $a' \in A$ such that $a' < s-p$. Now combine those inequalities and observe that $a-a' > (p+r) + (p-s)$ *i.e.* $a-a' > 2p + r-s > p$. This contradicts the fact that $p$ is an upper bound of $A_1$, so we do not have have $p < s-r$.

We have proved that $s-r$ is the least upper bound of $A_1$, *i.e.* it is its supremum.

You should be able to do the second question now !

The takeaway is that whenever you are in doubt, just go back to the basic definitions, and you won't feel as if you were invoking some kind of magic formula such as $\sup  A + sup B = sup(A+B)$ without understanding anything.

Comment: Thank you the proof helped a lot. So basically the answer lies in the definition of sup and inf!!